# Start-up error message QGIS 1.8 Couldn't load PyQt4

Tags: qgis

After successfully building QGIS 1.8 "Lisboa" on Windows 7 in 32 bit mode by following the instructions mentioned [here](http://www.qgis.org/api/INSTALL.html#toc14) I am able to start QGIS, however I get the following startup error message:

> Couldn't load PyQt4. Python support will be disabled.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  ImportError:
>   DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>
> QGIS version:
>   1.8.0-Lisboa 'Lisboa', exported

After this message the Python console and other python related plugins are not loaded.

I have installed the latest PyQt installer of PyQt4.9.5 from [riverbanks](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)

My system details

OS: windows 7 64 bit

Build tools:

1. MS Visual Studio 2010
2. C-Make 2.8.8
3. Python2.7
4. PyQt4.9.5 with SIP
5. OSGeo4W with GRASS and all dependency libs

further investigation lead me to believe that there might be a mismatch of PyQt 4.9.5 that I installed and the one downloaded by OSGeo4W (PyQt4.8). However, I do not know how to make the cmake look for pyQt4.9.5 instead of PyQt4.8

I would highly appreciate any pointers and detailed help in solving this issue.

With regards

Sukesh

Comment: Perhaps the installer would give you success? http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#12-OSGeo4W-Installer  What is your use case?

Comment: Thank you for your response Willy. My use case is as following:

Comment: I need to customize QGIS, hence need to build it from sources and add few customized algorithms to it. I have been able to build QGIS successfully except for the python part. I would appreciate if you could point out how I can resolve PyQt mismatch. Will OSGeo4W libs be updated with PyQt4.9.5 in near future? if not where can I get PyQt4.8 version. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you try the dev mailing list?  http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer